# inline scripts: jQuery is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys,
i have a certain plugin on my website that adds a inline script segment to my website.

this is the first line of this inline script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
```

jquery 1.5 is loaded in my head. However in my normal script.js file where all my selfmade js is stored I use...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Anyway... my problem is that this inline script with `jQuery(document)...`causes my console to shout: "jQuery is not defined"...

any idea how to fix that? I can't access the inline script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these before your jquery call:
jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin ends up adding its own scripts before jQuery gets pulled in then yes you will run into this problem. Will you be able to point us to the actual page?

You might want to lazy load the plugin if possible.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and $ (usually) refer to the same thing. Check if your jQuery libraries are loaded BEFORE (ie are higher in the HEAD section) your plugin..

Comment: I'm using head.js to load multiple javascript files. jQuery is one of those files loaded with head.js... this is causing the problem. Any idea how I could solve that!